# Rails: add form field value to data confirm message?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

How to I add the form data that a user has entered to the data-confirm message?

```
= form_for(@booking, html: { class: "form-horizontal", role: "form" }) do |f|

    .form-group.emails
      = f.label :emails,'Any other emails to add?', class: "col-sm-2 control-label"
      .col-sm-10
        = f.text_field :emails, class: "form-control", placeholder: 'email address separated by a comma'       

.form-group
  .text-center
  = f.submit "Send dates",
  data: { confirm: "Are these email addresses correct? {add email addresses here..}" }, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

I want to add the emails entered in the email field by the user.
So if a user enters the address 
`user@example.com`
, the confirm message would be

> "Are these email addresses correct? user@example.com"

Comment: you have to use jquery/javascript when user change anything in email fields just update message based on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#email_fields").change(function(){
    $('.email-button input').data('confirm', "Are these email addresses correct?  " + $("#email_fields").val())
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery & assign ids to your fields like

```
= f.text_field :emails, class: "form-control", placeholder: 'email address separated by a comma', id: "email_fields" 

= f.submit "Send dates",id: "submit_button"
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit_button").click(function(event) {
        if( !confirm('Are these email addresses correct?'+ $("#email_fields").val() ) 
            event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: that just gives me an error  "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: event.preventDefault();

Comment: ok, try $(this.form).submit(); instead of event.preventDefault();